# HTMLEditor (From AJAXToolkit) Check if content is empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an HTMLEditor in my aspx file with id = "txtText"

I am trying to write a JQuery function which checks if the content of the editor is empty.

I originally had:

```
function check()
{
    if($('#txtText').val() == '')
    {
         return false;
    }
    return true
}
```

However when I added an alert box to find out why this doesn't work. I realized that the .val() property of the HTMLEditor is always undefined (whether the editor has text or has no text).

I tried using $('#txtText').content(), which is how I am accessing the data in the code-behind(C#), but that does not seem to work in JQUERY.

After doing some research I found this site: http://forums.asp.net/t/1549543.aspx/1

I have very smiliar code, such that I also made my own custom editor which inherits from the one in AJAXToolkitEditor.

```
<cc1:CustomEditor ID="txtEditor" Height="600px" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="getImageContent()"
    runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="saveContent" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

The posted code does not work for me:

```
function getImageContent() {
var editor = $find("txtEditor");
var editPanel = editor.get_editPanel();
var designPanel = editPanel.get_modePanels()[0];
var s = designPanel.get_content();

document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = s;
```

}

The line var editor = $find("txtEditor") is a null value.

Comment: Which kind of HTMLEditor? Is it using Iframe?

Comment: It's from the AJAXControlToolkit

Comment: So ya, its using an iframe to render content. You need to point to the content body of this iframe, not directly to #txtText element. You could try this assuming there is no other iframe in your page: $('iframe').contents().find('body').html()

Comment: @roasted I think this is the correct approach.

Comment: @roasted I tried your snippet of code and it was a null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need to get the generated [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) (something like `ctl00_txtEditor`) using a bit of server script (`<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>`)

**HTMLEditor:**

Sort hack-ish but this should determine if there is an content in an [`HTMLEditor`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) control client-side (server-side is easy to check via `txtEditor.Content`)

jQuery:

```
$('#<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').find('iframe').eq(2).contents().find('body').html()
```

**HTMLEditorExtender:**

This works for the [`HTMLEditorExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HtmlEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx) which is [recommended](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) over using the `HTMLEditor` control

> Note: We recommend that you use the new HtmlEditorExtender instead of
>   the HtmlEditor control described on this page. The HtmlEditorExtender
>   takes advantage of HTML5 and works with IE6 and later.

jQuery:

```
$('#<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').val()
```

or JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').value
```

Comment: I added in ClientIDMode = AutoID for my text box and tried running your suggest JS. However, it said "incaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null " in the console (google chrome)

Comment: You might consider using the [`HTMLEditorExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HtmlEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx), the demo site even recommends it: `We recommend that you use the new HtmlEditorExtender instead of the HtmlEditor `.  The example above will work with that control

Comment: @Rhs updated answer adding a solution for the `HTMLEditor` since it is in an iframe checking the value is a bit hackish client-side, but checking server-side is rather simple, that may be preferred when using this control.

Comment: I tried
    $('#<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').find('iframe').eq(2).contents().find('body').html()

it returned some function definition.

Comment: do you have a test site you can share? the above script worked fine on the demo site (after adding jQuery to the page).  Are you sure the last paren `()` was there after `html`?

Comment: Correction it says null. I don't have a site I can show unfortunately. what does the .eq(2) part mean? Thanks though!

Comment: just doing `$('#<%=txtEditor.ClientID%>').find('iframe')` results in 4 iframes within the editor, the 3rd one contains values keyed into the editor, [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selects a specific jQuery element using a 0-based index.